# Python, how to create a table from JSON data - indexing

Tags: python, json, pandas, indexing

I am trying to create a table from JSON data. I have already used the json.dumps for my data:
this is what I am trying to export to the table:

```
label3 = json.dumps({'class': CLASSES[idx],"confidence": str(round(confidence * 100, 1)) + "%","startX": str(startX),"startY": str(startY),"EndX": str(endX),"EndY": str(endY),"Timestamp": now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M")})
```

I have tryied with:

```
val1 = json.loads(label3)
df = pd.DataFrame(val1)
print(df.T)
```

The system gives me an error that I must pass an index.

And also with:

```
val = ast.literal_eval(label3)
val1 = json.loads(json.dumps(val))
print(val1)
val2 = val1["class"][0]["confidence"][0]["startX"][0]["startY"][0]["endX"][0]["endY"][0]["Timestamp"][0]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=val2, columns=["class", "confidence", "startX", "startY", "EndX", "EndY", "Timestamp"])
print(df)
```

When I try this, the error it gives is that String indices mustb be integers.

How can I create the index?

Thank you,

Comment: post the actual error don't type it

Comment: To the pd.DataFrame function, you can pass the index as follows: pd.DataFrame(val1,index=list(range(number_of_rows)))

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways we can tackle this issue.

1. Do as directed by the error, pass the index to the dataframe function

```
pd.Dataframe(val1, index=list(range(number_of_rows)) # number of rows is 1 in your case.
```

2. While dumping the data using json.dumps, dump dictionary which has the mapping from key:list of values instead of key:value. For example

```
json.dumps({ 'class': [ CLASSES[idx] ],"confidence": [ ' some confidence ' ] })
```

I have shortened your given example. See I am passing values as list of values(even if it is only one value per key).